# Call the same function when clicking the Button and pressing enter

Tags: python, events, python-3.x, tkinter, event-handling

I have a GUI that has `Entry` widget and a submit `Button`.

I am basically trying to use `get()` and print the values that are inside the `Entry` widget. I wanted to do this by clicking the *submit* `Button` or by pressing *enter* or *return* on keyboard.

I tried to bind the `"<Return>"` event with the same function that is called when I press the submit Button:

```
self.bind("<Return>", self.enterSubmit)
```

But I got an error:

> needs 2 arguments

But `self.enterSubmit` function only accepts one, since for the `command` option of the `Button` is required just one.

To solve this, I tried to create 2 functions with identical functionalities, they just have different number of arguments.

Is there a more efficient way of solving this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a function that takes any number of arguments like this:

```
def clickOrEnterSubmit(self, *args):
    #code goes here
```

This is called an [arbitrary argument list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists). The caller is free to pass in as many arguments as they wish, and they will all be packed into the `args` tuple. The Enter binding may pass in its 1 `event` object, and the click command may pass in no arguments.

Here is a minimal Tkinter example:

```
from tkinter import *

def on_click(*args):
    print("frob called with {} arguments".format(len(args)))

root = Tk()
root.bind("<Return>", on_click)
b = Button(root, text="Click Me", command=on_click)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Result, after pressing `Enter` and clicking the button:

```
frob called with 1 arguments
frob called with 0 arguments
```

If you're unwilling to change the signature of the callback function, you can wrap the function you want to bind in a `lambda` expression, and *discard* the unused variable:

```
from tkinter import *

def on_click():
    print("on_click was called!")

root = Tk()

# The callback will pass in the Event variable, 
# but we won't send it to `on_click`
root.bind("<Return>", lambda event: on_click())
b = Button(root, text="Click Me", command=frob)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also assign a default value (for example `None`) for the parameter `event`. For example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_click(event=None):
    if event is None:
        print("You clicked the button")
    else:
        print("You pressed enter")


root = tk.Tk()
root.bind("<Return>", on_click)
b = tk.Button(root, text='Click Me!', command=on_click)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```