# Event binding with widget in tkinter in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I have written a sample code in python 2.7. I have created a button and i want to associate this button with "F2" key of keyboard also i want that if i click on button "Click me", i want the same result. This code is not working fine. If anyone have idea, tell me. I have asked this question just to know how to use other keyboard keys like F1 to F12 or Alt etc.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def callback(event):
    print "hi"

b = Button(root, text="Click me") 
b.pack()
b.bind("<F2>", callback)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm not able to understand your question. If the button is pressed you want the same functionality of whatever your F2 button does, to be executed?

Comment: Yes, i want the same result, if click on the "click me" button and if i press "F2" button of my keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work. I couldn't make your question exactly but this would solve the issue I presume.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def callback(*args):
    print("hi")

root.bind("<F2>", callback)
b = Button(root, text="Click me") 
b.pack()
b.config(command = callback)
root.mainloop()
```

You need to bind the  key to the function before or after you add the button to root.

Comment: Thanks, It is working fine. But can you please tell me, why you have binded the "root" with "F2" button of keyboard ?  Why have you not binded "b" with  "F2" button of keyboard ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the answer to this question:
[Call the same function when clicking the Button and pressing enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747058/call-the-same-function-when-clicking-the-button-and-pressing-enter)

The code example he gives should help you with your code as well. Besides the `b.pack()` command probably needing to be after the bind call, your button should have a command associated with it: `b = Button(root, text="Click Me", command=callback)`